# tinyMCE in tinyMCePopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I created a plugin which open a tinyMCEPopup. The tinyMCEPopup is a html file with a form and i need to have a tinyMCE textarea in it. here is the structure of the popup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <textarea id="mceEditor"></textarea>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use:

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'mceEditor');
or
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'mceEditor');
```

and the tinyMCE.init() function but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information. E.g. What isn't it doing, what error messages is it giving, what is it actually doing.

Comment: The popup shows a normal textarea without tinyMCE editor, no error messages.

Comment: Step through your code to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", true, 'mceEditor');
```